# How to reference public GitHub packages from maven project

Tags: maven, github-package-registry

I have a GitHub repo with a library published to its own GitHub packages maven repository. And I also have another project where I want to reference this library as a dependency.

When I add the following configuration to the POM file of my project it just doesn't work.

```
<repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>github</id>
  <name>GitHub Packages</name>
  <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/test-account/test-lib</url>
 </repository>
</repositories>
```

It requires me to authenticate. I understand that this is pretty logical as it is basically not a sources repo but an underlying maven repo. But is there a way to have normal maven access to this dependency? My library is in the public repo.

P.S. Please, do not suggest using Jitpack as I would like to have clean solution without any additional resources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer seems to be "you can't". See [this comment from a GitHub staff member](https://github.community/t/how-to-allow-unauthorised-read-access-to-github-packages-maven-repository/115517/3):

> Our Maven service doesn’t allow for unauthorized access right now. We plan to offer this in the future but need to improve the service a bit before that.

For now the simplest option seems to be to create a personal access token with read access and include it in the URL of the `<repository>` section in your `pom.xml`, like this:

```
<repository>
  <id>github</id>
  <name>GitHub Packages</name>
  <url>https://my-user:b96e7de7514e45c5@maven.pkg.github.com/my-user/my-repo</url>
</repository>
```

Otherwise, options are probably:

- Create a personal access token with read access and just share it with the whole world.
- Use the workaround [described here](https://github.community/t/how-to-allow-unauthorised-read-access-to-github-packages-maven-repository/115517/4)
- Publish to Maven Central (but that's a whole world of pain)

Comment: In the end I have published to Bintray.

Comment: @AlexeyAnufriev I found out you can just include the access token in the URL. That might be the way to go for now. I've updated my answer.

But for anything but a very trivial setup, I don't think GitHub Packages is the best way to go if you're using Maven. It also sucks that you need a separate repository declaration for each dependency since you can't just do https://maven.pkg.github.com/my-user to get access to all artifacts from all projects in your GitHub org.

Comment: That is nice, just do not want to expose any credentials. But for the completeness of the answer it is very useful.

Comment: small update: Creating a personal access token with read only access to package and including in the pom.xml triggers GitGuardian - automatically revoking the key. So this is not a solution unless GitGuardian is disabled for the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, you cannot. There is an ongoing discussion [here](https://github.community/t/download-from-github-package-registry-without-authentication/14407/) with this feature request. You can find multiple workarounds in that discussion thread and also voice your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

**The accepted answer no longer works**.

Currently GitGuardian automatically revokes the Personal Access Token (PAT) if that method is applied in public repositories. As recommended by [GitHub staff](https://github.community/t/download-from-github-package-registry-without-authentication/14407/111), the work-around solution is the following:

1. Create a PAT with just the read:packages scope
2. Execute docker run ghcr.io/jcansdale/gpr encode

This will output the following:

```
$ docker run ghcr.io/jcansdale/gpr encode 0123456789abcsef
An encoded token can be included in a public repository without being automatically deleted by GitHub.
```

These can be used in various package ecosystems like this:

```
A NuGet `nuget.config` file:
<packageSourceCredentials>
  <github>
    <add key="Username" value="PublicToken" />
    <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="&#48;123456789abcsef" />
  </github>
</packageSourceCredentials>

A Maven `pom.xml` file:
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>github-public</id>
    <url>https://public:&#48;123456789abcsef@maven.pkg.github.com/<OWNER>/*</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

An npm `.npmrc` file:
@OWNER:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken="\u0030123456789abcsef"
You can use this snippet in you project’s configuration file.
```

Note, you shouldn’t include your own read:packages PAT if you have access to any private packages you need to protect. In this case it is best to create a machine-user.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider as additional resource a Gradle plugin, then I'd suggest you [mine](https://github.com/elect86/magik)

I was exactly in your shoes, you can either:

- have a Github repository acting as a Maven repository
- or publish on Github Packages and easier the consumption for Gradle
  clients